# Node.js/Passport.js work flow

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am using the sample Passport.js Local strategy from [this github repo](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). I am trying to get an understanding of the flow of the requests and what get's called and when. However when I add these two lines:

```
app.use(passport.initialize(console.log('initialize')));
app.use(passport.session(console.log('session')));
```

..it seems they only `console.log()` when I first start the server. Shouldn't they `console.log()` on every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Passport.initialize()` runs only once, when the app server is started.
It is required to initialize `passport` in the Application server, Thus it runs only once.

Same case is with `passport.session()`.

From PassportJs Documentation:

> In a Connect or Express-based application, `passport.initialize()`
>   middleware is required to initialize `Passport`. If your application
>   uses persistent login sessions, `passport.session()` middleware must
>   also be used.

For more information, Please go through [Passport Documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs).